# Frustrating PDO error?

Tags: php, database, pdo

I'm just dabbling with PDO for the first time, and I keep getting an error that I really can't figure out, the code causing the problem is as follows:

```
            <?php
                try {
                    // Querying the database
                    $STH = $DBH->query("SELECT 'Group' from 'GroupTable'");
                    // Setting the fetch mode
                    $STH->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); 

                    while($row = $STH->fetch()) {
                        echo '<option value="',$row['Group'],'">',$row['Group'],'</option>';
                    }
                } 
                catch(PDOException $e) {
                    echo "Error connecting to Database";
                    file_put_contents('logs/logsDB.txt', $e->getMessage(), FILE_APPEND);
                }
            ?>
```

I keep getting the same error, namely:

> SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an
>   error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your
>   MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''GroupTable''
>   at line 1

I've tried quoting/unquoting the table/column name, when unquoted I get this error:

> SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an
>   error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your
>   MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'Group FROM
>   GroupTable' at line 1

I'd checked and double checked, the Table is DEFINITELY called GroupTable and the column is definitely called Group.

I'm sorry if this is something really obvious or nooby, I'm just trying to mess around with this and see if I can learn the basics, apologies if the code doesn't conform to standards etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two problems here:

- `GROUP` [is a reserved word in mySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html), so it'll work only when quoted.
- Table and column names need to be quoted using backticks, not simple quotes:

  ```
  SELECT `Group` from `GroupTable`
  ```

Comment: Thanks! Turns out the backticks were the problem here, although I find it strange for them to decide on backticks when quotes are used everywhere else in the language (this is the first time I've had to use backticks)

Comment: @SeanDunwoody: Quotes are used to represent **strings** where ticks are used to represent **table and database names**.

Comment: I understand, it's just strange when these things ' ' used to work in the old SQL queries I'm used to, I'm not sure why they decided to switch from this ' ' to this ` `